# Simple blur of img images with javascript or canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I am aware of all some of the jquery libraries that do that but they all just blur background images.

Im trying to create a backup effect in case the browser doesnt support css3 filters.

An idea I had was to inject svg tags around an images and apply and svg effect there. Would this work?

I would love to hear some advice.

**What I tried:**

```
<svg>
<filter id="blur">
  <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="8"/>
</filter>
  <image src:href="images/football.png" width="200" height="158" filter="url(#blur)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: What have you try'd yourself? show us some code atleast:)

Comment: Ok sure. I will, give me a sec

Comment: @Katherina here I have an example of what I tried. Svg filters work on all modern browsers including ie10-11 right? So this could be a great polyfill for images, where text-shadow can be used to blur text.

Comment: Just how exactly do I make this work? I would keep the original markup untouched and then inject this. Im using the picture element and srcset so its abit confusing to implement

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you have a mistake in your `image` element. The attribute `src:href` should be `xlink:href`.

Here is a funny example of how to blur all the `<img>` contained in a web page. Try it on any web page with the Firefox Scratchpad (Shift-F4).

```
function svg(tag, attribs, children) {
    var namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    var e = document.createElementNS(namespace, tag);
    if (typeof attribs === 'undefined') attribs = {};
    var k;
    for (k in attribs) {
        if (k.substr(0, 6) == 'xlink:') {
            e.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", k.substr(6), attribs[k]);
        } else {
            e.setAttribute(k, attribs[k]);
        }
    }
    if (Array.isArray(children)) {
        children.forEach(
            function(child) {
                e.appendChild(child);
            }
        );
    }
    return e;
}

var images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
for (var i = 0 ; i < images.length ; i++) {
    var img = images[i];
    var dim = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    var ele = svg(
        "svg",
        {width: dim.width, height: dim.height},
        [
            svg(
                "defs", {},
                [
                    svg(
                        "filter", {id: "BLUR"},
                        [
                            svg("feGaussianBlur", {stdDeviation: 3})
                        ]
                    )
                ]
            ),
            svg(
                "image", {
                    filter: "url(#BLUR)",
                    x: 0,
                    y: 0,
                    width: dim.width,
                    height: dim.height,
                    "xlink:href": img.src
                }
            )
        ]
    );
    img.parentNode.replaceChild(ele, img);
    console.log(dim);
    console.log(ele.outerHTML);
}
```